# Creating a test package that does nothing but consume CPU cycles

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'd like to create a package that does no useful work but uses lots of CPU. This is to test an SSIS load balancing solution.

I've got a pretty good idea how to do nothing for a given amount of time, I'd just to consume lots of CPU doing nothing while not making this overly complex. I'm thinking of doing something like pulling a string apart and some rigorous computations in a loop container. Or maybe hitting some web service? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just an empty "busy loop"?

Comment: How much CPU could that use? Easy enough to test though, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I'd think a script task using the crypto libraries would be where CPU cycles could be easily burnt

Comment: @Metaphor: It would be spending all its time checking whether it's time to stop, i.e. "Is it time to stop? Is it time to stop? Is it time to stop? ...".

Comment: @billinkc great idea! encrypt a few dozen paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum in a tight loop. That should keep those cores churning.

Answer (score 1):

Consuming CPU time doesn't necessarily require executing something complex, just that the CPU is kept busy.  Multiple web services calls may take time to execute but won't necessarily tie up the CPU as the processor may do other things while it waits for the I/O involved with the service calls to complete.

What about a Script Task containing this?

```
        var executeForSeconds = 10;

        var limit = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(executeForSeconds);
        while (DateTime.Now <= limit)
        {
            var x = 1*1;
        }
```